# iOS application using USB MSC or MTP(Mass Storage or Media Transfer Protocol)

Tags: ios, iphone, usb, mtp, usb-mass-storage

currently I'm considering the iOS application like below,

Application:
Using the lightning USB3 camera adapter, by MSC(Mass Storage Class) or MTP(Media Transfer Protocol), 
browse and copy files from devices which have USB connector to iPhone.

Lightning USB3 camera adapter

[http://www.apple.com/jp/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-usb-3カメラアダプタ](http://www.apple.com/jp/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-usb-3%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A2%E3%83%80%E3%83%97%E3%82%BF)

I asked Apple, with TSI(Technical Support Incident) for creating such iOS application, and they said iOS SDK doesn't support MSC / MTP.

By using Apple's USB Host Adapter(Lightning USB3 Camera Adapter), is there any way to create application to browse files in connected device by USB cable with MSC or MTP ?

I'd appreciate if you would answer the questions or give me some information.

Thank you.